# How to implement BLE proximity profile in cc 2540

Tags: android, bluetooth, embedded, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to implement a loss and found application using BLE device and android app, where BLE device will be with object and if the android phone with app comes in the vicinity of the object, it can detect and find the object. So far I went through [Proximity profile](https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/profiles/Pages/ProfileViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.profile.proximity.xml), [a pdf document on proximity profile](https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/downloaddoc.ashx?doc_id=239392), and few BLE quick start guide from developer.bluetooth.org site.

I am not understanding how to go about this implementatio, what is required to do on BLE device and whats the requirement to write android app for that. Are there any good documentation or site, where I can learn about this ?

Answer (score 1):

Texas Instruments, the manufacturer of the CC2540/2541 chips provides a lot of support for developers that may be useful to you. First, the BLE software stack is provided free here:

http://www.ti.com/tool/ble-stack

There are also a couple developer's kits that will help you build Android/iOS apps. The SensorTag is relatively cheap ($25), and there are full source code examples of both Android/iOS apps that connect to the SensorTag.

SensorTag: http://www.ti.com/ww/en/wireless_connectivity/sensortag/index.shtml?keyMatch=sensortag&tisearch=Search-EN

SensorTag Android/iOS source code: http://www.ti.com/tool/sensortag-sw

The TI Remote Control kit is a little more advanced (and expensive), but it includes a bluetooth packet sniffer and the CC debugger, which you will need to program your CC254x chip.

Remote Control Kit: http://www.ti.com/tool/cc2541dk-rc?keyMatch=cc2541%20remote&tisearch=Search-EN

To develop on the CC254x, you will need to download IAR Embedded Workbench for 8051 (link below). A word of caution, once you install, the trial version will only last 30 days, after which you will need to buy a license, which for one user will cost ~$3k.

http://www.iar.com/Products/IAR-Embedded-Workbench/8051/

You can find a lot of helpful documentation in the TI websites I linked to you above, especially if you search through the "Technical Documents" sections. Here is a particularly useful one, the BLE software developer's guide:

http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/swru271f/swru271f.pdf

This should get you started. It sure helped me a lot :)

Comment: It doesn't make sense to advice SensorTag for proximity purpose, since it does not have an integrated buzzer like the CC2540 kit. Thus, SensorTag will be useless in this case.